# Full system clone, snapshot using rsync

Tags: linux, backup, rsync, clone, disk-cloning

I have automated backups running on my ubuntu box using rsnapshot (rsync) basically following this [tutorial](http://nixjedi.com/rsnapshot-automated-rsync-backups-debian-ubuntu-using-ssh-keys/).
My concern is how to restore if everything is lost. Since it does not seem that I can backup the entire drive and that I have to choose individual folders and some like proc/ cause problems.

Currently in my rsnapshot.conf I have (see below). Is there a way to just clone the entire drive? Or should I not do this?

Questions:

1, Can I backup in a way such that it is a clone of the drive so that it can be swapped with the current drive?

2, If not yes to clone, If I had a total drive failure would I install a basic ubuntu and then replace all the files with the backups?

3, Anything I might not know about that I should.

Thanks

```
###############################
### BACKUP POINTS / SCRIPTS ###
###############################

# LOCALHOST
backup  /var/           localhost/
backup  /home/          localhost/
backup  /etc/           localhost/
backup  /lib/           localhost/
backup  /usr/           localhost/
backup  /opt/           localhost/
backup  /root/          localhost/
backup  /sbin/          localhost/
backup  /selinux/       localhost/
backup  /srv/           localhost/
###backup /proc/          localhost/
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the `-x` option to `rsync`, so that it doesn't recurse into other filesystems (such as `/proc`, `/sys`, etc.). The easiest way to do that is to pass `-x` to `rsnapshot`. If you do have several disk filesystems (e.g. `/home` separate from `/`), list them all as backup points.

Whether you should back up everything depends on how fast you want recovery to be. For example everything under `/usr` that is not under `/usr/local` can be recovered by reinstalling the distribution. But that will increase your recovery time.

You can reconstruct a mostly identical system with just the complete content of `/etc` and `/usr/local`, plus the list of installed packages obtained with `dpkg --get-selections`. To restore, install the basic distribution, run `dpkg --set-selections` on the package list, then `apt-get install` and finally restore `/etc/` and `/usr/local`.

The backup won't be bootable unless you make it so. If you have a copy of the whole disk, I think `sudo chroot /path/to/backup/root grub-install /dev/sdb` (where `sdb` identifies the disk containing the backup) should do the trick. Maybe you need to set up a correct device map first, I'm not sure.

You can make a clone of the whole disk; this is best done with the filesystems not mounted, otherwise you'll make a copy with an inconsistent filesystem. The easiest way to do this is to use `gparted` from a live CD/USB. You can also use `parted` on the command line, or `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=16M` to copy `/dev/sda` to `/dev/sdb` (be very careful as a one-character typo will erase your data with no warning).

If you've prepared things in advance, you can make the copy from a live system, and faster. 
* If you've set your disk as a (single) component in a RAID-1 array: add the second disk to the array, reconstruct the array, remove the second disk from the array (`mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/sdb`, wait, `mdadm /dev/md0 --fail /dev/sdb --remove /dev/sdb`).
* If you've set up your filesystem(s) on LVM volumes, and you have enough room for a snapshot, you can copy the raw filesystem from the snapshot.

Once you've made the clone, you can use `rsync` to keep it up to date. This won't take care of keeping old file versions around; you can stick with rsnapshot for that.